# Angular material broken after angular 9 update

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I recently update my project from Angular 8 to 9, but there are issues with angular material imports. I also updated angular material.

But angular material imports are giving errors.
I also tried uninstalling and adding angular-material but no luck.
What should I do now?
Thank you in advance

```
     import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
        import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

        import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
        import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
        import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
        import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
        import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
        import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
        import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatCardModule,
],
exports:[
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatGridListModule,
],

        })
        export class AppMaterialModule { }
```

app.module

```
import { AppMaterialModule } from '../app/app-material/app-material.module';

imports : [AppMaterialModule ]
```

These imports are giving error.
Where as  `MatCardModule, MatAutocompleteModule` not giving any error

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and the way I solved it was importing 'AppMaterialModule' on every module that it's being used.
Let's say that you have a LoginModule and DashboardModule, you have to add 'AppMaterialModule' on imports array of those 2 modules named before, it's not gonna work if you just add it on AppModule.

Also consider:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

and add it to 'schemas' array on the required module.

```
...

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMAS ]
})
export class AppModule { }
...
```

If you have any other problem with the update, you can actually check this link where you can find a guide to update Angular !

Step by step update: [Angular update Guide](https://update.angular.io/)